# datetimepicker select a value after dropdown instead of on dropdown C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have an datetimepicker issue on winform. When the form loads, I initializes the datetimepicker as

```
DateIdentifier.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
DateIdentifier.CustomFormat = " ";
DateIdentifier.Value = DateTime.Now;
```

then, it retrieves value from datagridview which in turn has datasource from a backend table, like this:

```
if (Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["DateIdentified"].Value) == "")
{
    DateIdentifier.CustomFormat = " ";
    DateIdentifier.Text = null;
}
else
{
   DateIdentifier.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
   DateIdentifier.Text = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["DateIdentified"].Value);
}
```

it works fine so far, but when I click on the drop down button, the current datetime stamp will overwrites whatever date time retrieved from the database, I guess it's because I set `DateIdentifier.Value = DateTime.Now`. Is there some way to maintain the textbox of the datetimepicker showing value from datagridview when dropdown is hit and only when I truly select a date in the accompany calendar, the new picked date will be showed in the textbox of the datetimepicker?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting the selectedDate of the datetime picker.

```
   if (Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["DateIdentified"].Value) == "")
    {
        DateIdentifier.CustomFormat = " ";
        DateIdentifier.Text = null;
    }
    else
    {
       DateIdentifier.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
       DateIdentifier.SelectedValue = DateTime.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["DateIdentified"].Value);
    DateIdentifier.Text = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["DateIdentified"].Value);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes I tried something like DateIdentifier.Value = DateTime.Parse(DateIdentifier.Text); And it worked